# Drawing QTreeView items with QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qstyleditemdelegate, qstyle

I have created a project based on the `Simple Tree Model Example` from the Qt examples list and edited its model so that some items can also be checked; this is how it looks like:

[image]

I would like some of the items to be slightly moved to the left. So I created a delegate by deriving `QStyledItemDelegate` and reimplemented `QStyledItemDelegate::paint` like this:

```
void TreeItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (index.column() == 0) {
        TreeItem *childItem = static_cast<TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());
        if (childItem->type() == TreeItem::Type::Checkable) {
            QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;
            QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(&opt, index);

            const int desiredThreshold = 10;

            opt.rect.setX(opt.rect.x() - desiredThreshold);
            option.widget->style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &opt, painter, option.widget);

            return;
        }
    }

    return QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
}
```

This way items of type `TreeItem::Type::Checkable` will be drawn to the left by the value of the `desiredThreshold` constant (in this case 10 pixels).

So far so good; everything works well and the drawing is done correctly. However...

The problem is that although the item is drawn slightly to the left(which is ok), the mouse events are still working as if the item didn't move at all; here's how it works:

[image]

Is it possible to tell the delegate that the whole item is drawn slightly to the left so that when I click on the checkbox(which was also moved together with the whole item) the model would be correctly updated?

Comment: I think you won't be able to avoid reimplementing the mouse event handlers as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Cause

You change how the `ItemViewItem` is rendered on the screen, but not how it responds to user actions.

## Solution

I would suggest you to reimplement [QStyledItemDelegate::editorEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#editorEvent); in order to adjust the position of the `QRect` returned by [QStyle::subElementRect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#subElementRect) when called with [QStyle::SE_ItemViewItemCheckIndicator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#SubElement-enum) as an argument.

## Example

Consider the following steps:

1. Add a public `editorEvent` method in your `TreeItemDelegate` class
2. Copy the [default implementation](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qstyleditemdelegate.cpp.html#_ZN19QStyledItemDelegate11editorEventEP6QEventP18QAbstractItemModelRK20QStyleOptionViewItemRK11QModelIndex) of `QStyledItemDelegate::editorEvent` into your code
3. Avoid the call to the private method of `QStyledItemDelegate` by changing

   ```
   const QWidget *widget = QStyledItemDelegatePrivate::widget(option);
   QStyle *style = widget ? widget->style() : QApplication::style();
   ```

   to

   ```
   QStyle *style = option.widget->style();
   ```
4. Adjust the position of `checkRect` by changing

   ```
   QRect checkRect = style->subElementRect(QStyle::SE_ItemViewItemCheckIndicator, &viewOpt, widget);
   ```

   to

   ```
   QRect checkRect = style->subElementRect(QStyle::SE_ItemViewItemCheckIndicator, &viewOpt, option.widget).adjusted(-10, 0, -10, 0);
   ```